# Which selector to use when trying to select element from within the same <li> tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to find a way to get the value from an inputfield within the same li tag as the button clicked, but can't figure out how. I've tried using the parent selector but can't get it to work.

Jquery-code

```
$('.addButton').live('click', function() {
var usedFood = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usedFood'));

//trying to get this value without using an ID
var preParse = $('#inputFieldFood').val();

//var preParse = $(this).parent().parent()

var temp = parseInt(preParse);

usedFood += temp;

$('.listAmount').html(usedFood);

localStorage.setItem('usedFood', JSON.stringify(usedFood));

temp = 0;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" class="content">
      <ul data-role="listview" id="categoryList">
          <li>
              <label class="listItemName">Food</label>
              <label class="listAmount"></label>
              <div class="textfieldContainer">
                  <input id="inputFieldFood" type=number pattern=[0-9]* inputmode=numeric>
              </div>
              <div class="buttonContainer">
                  <a data-role="button" class="addButton">+</a>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li id="addNew"><a>Add new category</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: live() is deprecated and removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) find the `li` element and then use the element-selector to find the `input` element within it

```
var preParse = $(this).closest('li').find('input').val();
```

Note: ID of an element must be unique, so if you have a repeated structure and wants to group similar elements then use class name instead of ID

```
<input class="inputFieldFood" type=number pattern=[0-9]* inputmode=numeric>
```

Comment: `$('#inputFieldFood').val();` what's wrong with this code.? OP's structure is having a single element with the id inputFieldFood. Right.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy since the OP talked about find the input in the same `li` we can make an educated guess that there are multiple `li` elements with the same pattern which means the id `inputFieldFood` will be repeated but the id selector will always return the first element with the given id

Comment: ok then why don't we make an educated guess that he might have been using Jquery version more than 1.9.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy because the OP complained about a very specific problem... not about nothing is working at all... but about a very specific value... so I guess the click handler should be working fine